# Lodash collection bulk update

Tags: javascript, collections, lodash

I want some code like this:

```
_.bulkUpdate(myCollection,'meta.type','new');
```

In other words, I want to update a field in my collection by a string or function, I know that this function is exist, but dont know its name

Answer (score 1):

You can bulk update in place by using [`_.forEach()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.3#forEach) to iterate the array, and then [`_.set()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.3#set) values, or [`_.update()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.3#set) using a function:

```js
var arr = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];

_.forEach(arr, function(item, index) {
  _.set(item, 'meta.type', 'new'); // to set a value
  _.update(item, 'meta.value', function() { return index; }); // to set with a function
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.3/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use [`_.update`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.3#update) or [`_.updateWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.3#updateWith)